Android Studio does not display project files, only “External Libraries” and “Scratches and Consoles” on a Flutter project
I recently reset my MacBook Air (M1) and reinstalled Xcode, Android Studio, and Flutter. Everything seems to work except for one issue in Android Studio:
Whenever I open a Flutter project (either a new project or one cloned from Git), Android Studio briefly displays the project files during indexing, but then they disappear, leaving only the following:

External Libraries
Scratches and Consoles

The project runs correctly when I use the terminal (flutter run), so the issue seems to be limited to the IDE.
Environment Details:

macOS: macOS 15.2 (M1 chip, darwin-arm64)
Android Studio: Ladybug | 2024.2.1 Patch 3
Flutter version: 3.27.0 (stable channel)
Dart version: 3.6.0

Environment Variables in .zshrc:
export PATH="$HOME/development/flutter/bin:$PATH"  
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/raulpalade/Library/ApplicationSupport/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts"  

Output from flutter doctor --verbose:
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.27.0, on macOS 15.2 24C101 darwin-arm64, locale it-IT)  
• Flutter version 3.27.0 on channel stable at /Users/raulpalade/development/flutter  
• Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git  
• Framework revision 8495dee1fd (5 days ago), 2024-12-10 14:23:39 -0800  
• Engine revision 83bacfc525  
• Dart version 3.6.0  
• DevTools version 2.40.2  

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)  
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 16.2)  
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web  
[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.2)  
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2024.3.1)  
[✓] VS Code (version 1.96.0)  
[✓] Connected device (4 available)  
[✓] Network resources  
• No issues found!  

When I keep Android Studio open, this issue repeatedly occurs: the project files briefly appear in the “Project” view during the indexing phase, but once indexing completes, they disappear, leaving only “External Libraries” and “Scratches and Consoles” visible.
Here are some images of the project settings:






delete file .idea and restart

Delete the (.idea) folder and (.iml) files in your project
restart Android Studio
